# Best way to split array of Int in continuously subrange Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of Int [0,1,2,5,6,7,11,12,13,14] and I would like to split it in different arrays like:

```
array1 = [0,1,2]
array2 = [5,6,7]
array3 = [11,12,13,14]
```

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: ArraySlice ? What is it exactly you want ? On what basis you want to split ? Maybe this : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/arrayslice

Comment: I need to split the array where the sequence stops. If you see the example the first array ends with 2 because there is no number 3 in the main array.

Comment: Can numbers repeat?

Comment: No there are only unique numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Following function compares neighbour numbers and decides where to put them.

```
func sliceInRanges(array: [Int]) -> [[Int]] {
    if array.isEmpty {
        return [[Int]]()
    }
    var slices: [[Int]] = [[]]
    var current: Int = 0

    for number in array {
        // Current slice is empty - first number of main array should be added to slices
        // Or difference from last number in current slice == 1
        if slices[current].isEmpty || number - 1 == slices[current].last!{
            slices[current].append(number)
        } else {
            slices.append([number])
            current += 1
        }
    }

    return slices
}

let array = [0,1,2,5,6,7,11,12,13,14]

print(sliceInRanges(array: array))
// Outputs [[0, 1, 2], [5, 6, 7], [11, 12, 13, 14]]
```